# How can I make the value of selected time as a range of hours in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want the value of selected times to be as a range as, (11:00am - 12:00pm) then the second value to be as (12:00pm - 01:00pm) and so on.

[As shown here in the first time value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omOsz.png)

I am using ReactTimePicker from react-ts-timepicker package.

```
<ReactTimePicker
    value={this.state.selectedTime} //I want here to be as range
    minTime={this.state.minTime} //09:00am
    maxTime={this.state.maxTime} //09:00pm
    step={60}
    onChange={this.handleChangeTime} 
    allowOnlySuggestions
    className="future-order-time-input"
    />

handleChangeTime = (e) => {
    //To get the format I want (hour,minutes,am/pm)
    let timeResult = this.parseTime(e, null);
    let time = this.getTime(timeResult);

    this.setState({ selectedTime: time });
};
```

Comment: Can you show us how you populate your time picker?

Comment: No, as per documentation, you can't do this at the moment. You should create a custom picker